# SQL group customers by age given date of birth

Tags: mysql, sql, datediff

I am trying to write an SQL script to group customers by age categories (0 - 10, 11 - 20, 21 - 30... 111 - 120) given only their date of birth. I know this will involve datediff by I just cant wrap my head around it. The ER diagram for my database is below, you can find the birthday in the personal_details table. all help greatly appreciated!!

[image]

Comment: Please add the the desired results with the query you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is probably to make a table with your age categories and make a join

```
SELECT *
FROM Personal_details p
INNER JOIN age_categories ac 
    ON TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.birthday, CURDATE()) 
        BETWEEN ac.age_min AND ac.age_max
```

---

An other way is with [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) but not as clear as a true table you can update to make new age categories...( 0-18; 18-30; ...)

For the CASE version :

```
SELECT *,
    CASE 
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.birthday, CURDATE())
            BETWEEN 0 AND 10 THEN '0-10'
        WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.birthday, CURDATE())
            BETWEEN 11 AND 20 THEN '11-20'
        -- ...
    END AS age_categorie

FROM Personal_details p
```

Comment: can you give an example using case please? I cant change the database.

Comment: @RHamilton updated, but the 1st option is still better if you can change your DB...

Comment: I tried your case version but it is just returning an age_catagorie column with all null values at the end of the table... Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @RHamilton you had to complet the WHEN : `WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, p.birthday, CURDATE()) BETWEEN @start@ AND @end@ THEN '@libelle_categorie@'`  but it work as expected : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/906e82/2